# Xamarin PositionID of label

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The problem is that I want to be able to latch onto the closest number and then center onto the labels and sort of center itself onto them properly, however I've got no idea how to do this. I would just like some tips on how to do this, as I'm pretty clueless.

I have figured out I need a way to get the position ID of labels and then if the draggable view is closer than maybe 10X and 10y it should center onto the label and that way latch onto. I've already made the draggableview

And then how do I acess this positionID from xamarin.droid or xamarin.ios?

Grid

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="White" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="10">
            <Label Text="Red" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
            <BoxView Color="Gray" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
            <Label Text="9" Font ="60" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="8" Font ="60" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="7" Font ="60" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="6" Font ="60" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="5" Font ="60" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="4" Font ="60" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="3" Font ="60" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="2" Font ="60" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="1" Font ="60" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="0" Font ="60" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />

            <local:DraggableView x:Name="dragView" DragMode="LongPress" DragDirection="All" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="3" >
                <local:DraggableView.Content>
                    <BoxView x:Name="image" BackgroundColor="Pink" />
                </local:DraggableView.Content>
            </local:DraggableView>
        </Grid>
```

Crossplatform Code, Xamarin

```
  public partial class DraggableView : ContentView
        {
            public event EventHandler DragStart = delegate { };
            public event EventHandler DragEnd = delegate { };

        public static readonly BindableProperty DragDirectionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "DragDirection",
        returnType: typeof(DragDirectionType),
        declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
        defaultValue: DragDirectionType.All,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public DragDirectionType DragDirection
    {
        get { return (DragDirectionType)GetValue(DragDirectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragDirectionProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty DragModeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
       propertyName: "DragMode",
       returnType: typeof(DragMode),
       declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
       defaultValue: DragMode.LongPress,
       defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public DragMode DragMode
    {
        get { return (DragMode)GetValue(DragModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragModeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsDraggingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      propertyName: "IsDragging",
      returnType: typeof(bool),
      declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
      defaultValue: false,
      defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public bool IsDragging
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDraggingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDraggingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty RestorePositionCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(RestorePositionCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(DraggableView), default(ICommand), BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnRestorePositionCommandPropertyChanged);

    static void OnRestorePositionCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var source = bindable as DraggableView;
        if (source == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        source.OnRestorePositionCommandChanged();
    }

    private void OnRestorePositionCommandChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("RestorePositionCommand");
    }

    public ICommand RestorePositionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(RestorePositionCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(RestorePositionCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public void DragStarted()
    {
        DragStart(this, default(EventArgs));
        IsDragging = true;
    }

    public void DragEnded()
    {
        IsDragging = false;
        DragEnd(this, default(EventArgs));
    }
```

Android Part of the code

```
public class DraggableViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.View>
    {
        float originalX;
        float originalY;
        float dX;
        float dY;
        bool firstTime = true;
        bool touchedDown = false;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            LongClick -= HandleLongClick;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            LongClick += HandleLongClick;
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            dragView.RestorePositionCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                if (!firstTime)
                {
                    SetX(originalX);
                    SetY(originalY);
                }

            });
        }
    }
    private void HandleLongClick(object sender, LongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        if (firstTime)
        {
            originalX = GetX();
            originalY = GetY();
            firstTime = false;
        }
        dragView.DragStarted();
        touchedDown = true;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    }
    protected override void OnVisibilityChanged(AView.View changedView, [GeneratedEnum] ViewStates visibility)
    {
        base.OnVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
        if (visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {



        }
    }

    // What happens when you toch
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        float x = e.RawX;
        float y = e.RawY;
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                if (dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
                {
                    if (!touchedDown)
                    {
                        if (firstTime)
                        {
                            originalX = GetX();
                            originalY = GetY();
                            firstTime = false;
                        }
                        dragView.DragStarted();
                    }
                    touchedDown = true;
                }
                dX = x - this.GetX();
                dY = y - this.GetY();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
                {
                    SetX(x - dX);
                }

                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
                {
                    SetY(y - dY);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                touchedDown = false;
                dragView.DragEnded();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                touchedDown = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {

        BringToFront();
        return true;
    }
}
```

iOS Part

```
public class DraggableViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<View>
{
    bool longPress = false;
    bool firstTime = true;
    double lastTimeStamp = 0f;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer panGesture;
    CGPoint lastLocation;
    CGPoint originalPosition;
    UIGestureRecognizer.Token panGestureToken;
    void DetectPan()
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        if (longPress || dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
        {
            if (panGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
            {
                dragView.DragStarted();
                if (firstTime)
                {
                    originalPosition = Center;
                    firstTime = false;
                }
            }

            CGPoint translation = panGesture.TranslationInView(Superview);
            var currentCenterX = Center.X;
            var currentCenterY = Center.Y;
            if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
            {
                currentCenterX = lastLocation.X + translation.X;
            }

            if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
            {
                currentCenterY = lastLocation.Y + translation.Y;
            }

            Center = new CGPoint(currentCenterX, currentCenterY);

            if (panGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
            {
                dragView.DragEnded();
                longPress = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            RemoveGestureRecognizer(panGesture);
            panGesture.RemoveTarget(panGestureToken);
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            panGesture = new UIPanGestureRecognizer();
            panGestureToken = panGesture.AddTarget(DetectPan);
            AddGestureRecognizer(panGesture);


            dragView.RestorePositionCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                if (!firstTime)
                {

                    Center = originalPosition;
                }
            });

        }

    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
        lastTimeStamp = evt.Timestamp;
        Superview.BringSubviewToFront(this);
        lastLocation = Center;
    }
    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.Timestamp - lastTimeStamp >= 0.5)
        {
            longPress = true;
        }
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
    }

}
```

Edit:

This is somewhat I want to do, I need to get the cordinates of each of the 10 labels, which I thought about doing in this method. And then I should place/center onto my label with use of set x and set y, but that part is easy. I'm not sure how to access the label properties in my xaml and how to do this for each of the 10 labels. Maybe I should put this in the code-behind of the grid and have  code in android/ios call upon it?

```
 public (double X, double Y) GetScreenCoordinates(VisualElement view)
        {
            var myLabel = MainPage.FindByName<Label>("MyLabel"); myLabel.MeasureInvalidated += (sender, args) => { double x; double y; if (myLabel.Bounds.X > 0) { x = myLabel.Bounds.X; } if (myLabel.Bounds.Y > 0) { y = myLabel.Bounds.Y; } };

            // A view's default X- and Y-coordinates are LOCAL with respect to the boundaries of its parent,
            // and NOT with respect to the screen. This method calculates the SCREEN coordinates of a view.
            // The coordinates returned refer to the top left corner of the view.

            // Initialize with the view's "local" coordinates with respect to its parent
            double screenCoordinateX = view.X;
            double screenCoordinateY = view.Y;

            // Get the view's parent (if it has one...)
            if (view.Parent.GetType() != typeof(App))
            {
                VisualElement parent = (VisualElement)view.Parent;


                // Loop through all parents
                while (parent != null)
                {
                    // Add in the coordinates of the parent with respect to ITS parent
                    screenCoordinateX += parent.X;
                    screenCoordinateY += parent.Y;

                    // If the parent of this parent isn't the app itself, get the parent's parent.
                    if (parent.Parent.GetType() == typeof(App))
                        parent = null;
                    else
                        parent = (VisualElement)parent.Parent;
                }
            }
            // Return the final coordinates...which are the global SCREEN coordinates of the view
            return (screenCoordinateX, screenCoordinateY);
        }
```

Comment: What is the positionID you mentioned ? Could you provide an illustration to describe your requirement and make us understand clear?

Comment: Edited to add more context, attempting to explain it a bit more